# Pow doesn't work - unable to find [myapp].dev

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localhost, rack-pow

Pow used to work for me a few months ago, but now it's not working for my new app, or for the ones that worked before.

I went into ~/.pow and created a symlink, but when I type MYAPPNAME.dev/ in my browser, it redirects to a cox(my internet provider) page saying "Sorry, the website subscriptions.dev cannot be found"

I read through all the docs in the pow page, and tried installing powify as well, but nothings working.

Is there something I may have done in my console (such as changing PATH or things) that may cause this to not work?

I tried restarting my computer as well, but still nothing..

=============================================================

Edit: Actually I just came to my office and it started working. Is it possible that my internet provider at home could be blocking/interfering with pow? I would assume that it's irrelevant since I thought pow was essentially a local host.

Comment: Any updates on this? I am getting the exact same problem. Cheers mate

Answer (score 1):

DNS hijacking from your ISP. Try setting your DNS server to 8.8.8.8 (google's DNS) and see if the problem persists.